# Dependency Injection AddSingleton instanciating multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I have a program in c#, dotnet 5.0, running on Linux Ubuntu, that registers a Singleton dependency:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
        services.AddGrpcReflection();
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<IExchangeService, HuobiAPI>();
        services.AddSingleton<IMarketWriter, MarketCSVWriter>();
    }
```

where HuobiAPI is

```
public class HuobiAPI : ExchangeServices
```

And HuobiAPI accepts gRPC calls.  One of the gRPC methods defined in ExchangeService is SubscribeMarket2UDP:

```
public override Task<SuccessReply> SubscribeMarket2UDP(
    MarketSubscriptionMessage request,
    ServerCallContext context)
```

Now, whenever this method is called (from a remote program), a new instance of ExchangeService is created.  However, my understanding is that this should be a singleton.

Is there any obvious reason for a AddSingleton dependency to create multiple instances of the same class?

Comment: By definition it will not. How do you know that it is?

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the constructor and see it hitting the constructor every time a new message arrives.  Also, local variables are all newly initialized.

Comment: Is your code in your question missing a call to `app.MapGrpcService<HuobiAPI>()`? I bet this call exists in your actual code base. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to the problem in "Dependency Injection: Principles, Practices, and Patterns - Steven van Deursen & Mark Seemann". Changing the registration of the dependency solved the problem.  For some reason that I don't yet fully understand doing:

```
services.AddSingleton<IExchangeService, HuobiAPI>();
```

is bad and I guess it is called a 'Torn Lifestyle'.

Now doing:

```
services.AddSingleton<HuobiAPI>();
services.AddSingleton<IExchangeService>(c => c.GetRequiredService<HuobiAPI>());
```

Works fine and only one instance of the HuobiAPI class is created.

If anybody has any comments or explanation for this, feel free to comment.  I'll have to dig more into the book to understand what is really going on here.

Comment: So you were registering the service under two different interfaces? That wasn't in your question, but that will do it.

Comment: What is likely happening is that the GRPC framework resolves `HuobiAPI` —not `IExchangeService`— from the DI Container, and when such registration for `HuobiAPI` does not exist, it creates it itself as transient.

Comment: This is not a [Torn Lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.org/diatl), because Torn Lifestyle happens when you have "multiple [registrations] with the same lifestyle [that] map to the _same_ component". Instead, what's happening here is called [Ambiquous Lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.org/diaal), because you "have multiple registrations with a different lifestyle map to the same component". In this case a Singleton registration for `HuobiAPI` made by you, and an implicit Transient 'registration' made by GRPC.

Comment: You can see [this behavior](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/7ef184f3c4cd62fbc3cde55e4bb3e16b58258ca1/src/Grpc.AspNetCore.Server/Internal/DefaultGrpcServiceActivator.cs#L37) implemented in the framework's internal [DefaultGrpcServiceActivator<T>](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/7ef184f3c4cd62fbc3cde55e4bb3e16b58258ca1/src/Grpc.AspNetCore.Server/Internal/DefaultGrpcServiceActivator.cs) class. Here you see it calls into the DI Container and when no registration exists, it falls back to creating a new instance on every call.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and for the "Ambiquous Lifestyle" explanation for gRPC.  Good to know!